# "Not found. Authentication passthru." error. Devise Omniauthable module doesn't work when it's inside another engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, omniauth

I tried putting Devise inside another mountable gem while following this guide: 
[How To: Use devise inside a mountable engine](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine).

Everything seems to be working fine except for the omniauth part. I'm trying to get [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) to work. I found out that [it's a known issue in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2692), but aside from having none of the proposed solutions work, I've noticed that the solution mentioned in that issue [has already been implemented inside Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L402-L443).

Here's what I've done so far:

**my_engine/my_engine.gemspec**

```
s.add_dependency 'omniauth'
s.add_dependency 'devise'
s.add_dependency 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

**my_engine/lib/my_engine.rb**

```
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
require 'devise'
```

**my_engine/config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET'], scope: 'email, profile'
```

**my_engine/config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'my_engine/omniauth_callbacks'}, class_name: "MyEngine::User", module: :devise
```

**my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class MyEngine::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = MyEngine::User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    user.update_attributes(name: auth.info.name)
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = 'Signed in!'
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :google_oauth2, :all
end
```

When I click "Sign in with Google OAuth2" it goes to `MyEngine::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru` directly and outputs "Not found. Authentication passthru". I've been digging through the source, but I can't figure out how Devise makes it go through the provider method instead of `#passthru`. Am I missing something here? I'm running on rails 4.1, Ruby 2.0, devise 3.2.4, and omniauth-oauth2 1.2.0.

Comment: I know it doesn't sound like a complete or perfect solution but can't you add a passthru action to your controller and deal with provider specific code in it?

Comment: Also, can you show us the result of rake routes for the devise/omniauth related paths?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The version I got working is very similar to the solutions discussed on the github issue page you linked to, but not identical (I've tweaked what I did slightly in the code below, because I also had a custom `:path` specified in my `devise_for`).  Also, I'm currently on devise 3.1.2 but hopefully that is sufficiently similar for the following to work for you.

In **my_engine/config/routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, :class_name => 'MyEngine::User', :module => :devise, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "my_engine/omniauth_callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
  # Had to add routes for callbacks here because otherwise the routes get
  # messed up -- prepending an extra "/my_engine" in one case.
  providers = Regexp.union(Devise.omniauth_providers.map(&:to_s))

  path_prefix = '/users/auth'

  match "#{path_prefix}/:provider",
    :constraints => { :provider => providers },
    :to => "omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
    :as => :user_omniauth_authorize,
    :via => [:get, :post]

  match "#{path_prefix}/:action/callback",
    :constraints => { :action => providers },
    :to => 'omniauth_callbacks',
    :as => :user_omniauth_callback,
    :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

in **my_engine/config/initializers/devise.rb**:

```
config.router_name = :my_engine
config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/my_engine/users/auth"
```

Some of this might be unnecessary, but I got it working like this after spending some time stepping through the flow with a debugger and haven't had time since to go back and try to make it more elegant/lean or anything.

Comment: I'm getting a `Invalid route name, already in use: 'user_omniauth_authorize'` error because Devise already creates the route. How did you solve that part?

Comment: I didn't get that error! I think this is because I'm still on rails 3.2.19 and I think that check was added as part of rails 4.  Adding `skip: :omniauth_callbacks` to your `devise_for` statement should stop the attempted duplication as it should prevent devise from generating those routes.

Comment: I tried adding the `skip: :omniauth_callbacks` to my `devise_for` and my fb login flow stopped working!  I had to add `Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
    ::OmniAuth::config.path_prefix = config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/my_engine/u/auth"
  end` just before the final `end` in my `my_engine\initializers\devise.rb`.  If this works for you, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I still get the same `Not found. Authentication passthru.` error. Did you override `OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru`? Because I didn't

Comment: And you've done the usual webrick/whatever restarting? That's strange. No, I didn't override the passthru method, I just implemented a facebook method. Assuming you don't get a log message output from omniauth saying something like `(facebook) Request phase initiated.`, I think your basic problem is that omniauth isn't noticing that you're trying to make the external auth call and stepping in to handle the flow. In `call!` in `omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb` you can see it checking path and calling other methods as appropriate. `on_request_path?` does the check for initial req. match.

Comment: This says to me that the omniauth `config.path_prefix` still isn't matching the actual path properly.  Perhaps it's not set, but that `... do ::OmniAuth::config.path_prefix = "/my_engine/users/auth" end` that I mentioned a couple of comments back should have set it.

Comment: Hi @TerencePonce, did you solve this in the end?  I'm genuinely interested.

Answer (score 0):

I find a better solution. Update your lib/MyEngine/engine.rb.
With this solution you do not have to add the devise scope section (my sample is only for facebook)

```
module MyEngine
  require 'omniauth'
  require 'omniauth-facebook'

  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace SimpleUser

    middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :scope => ENV['FACEBOOK_SCOPE']
  end
end
```

Comment: this doesn't generate any Engine route without changes in `routes.rb` for me